# Remove form parameter from binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, entity-framework-6

I have a form with some fields, and depending of the data i dont want to save all to database.

lets say, i have this controler

```
 public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "id,Costumer, City ,Obs")] Clients clients)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)

                db.Entry(clients).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(clients);
        }
```

but i somecases i dont want to save the City.

How can i remove the City from being save to database ?

I've tryied with

```
ModelState.Remove("City");
```

but it keeps saving to database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If City is a navigation property, then something like:

```
db.Entry(clients.City).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

if City is a string then

```
db.Entry(clients).Property("City").IsModified = false;
```

Comment: Hi, Visual Studio throws an error saying ´System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type String is not part of the model for the current context´

Comment: Thank you David. After i put the   db.Entry(clients).Property("City").IsModified = false;  after db.Entry(clients).State = EntityState.Modified; it starts working like i needed.